# how to create read only user in activeMQ web console

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm trying to create a read only user in activeMQ console, I found [this](https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/202653688-How-can-fine-grained-access-control-be-enabled-for-the-ActiveMQ-administrative-console-2008351-draft-) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050373/read-only-web-console-access-in-activemq) too.  the second post from stackoverflow is not helpful because it deployed the web console to an external server. The second page from pivotal looks promising and I tried with activeMQ version 5.14.1 but it didn't work too. activeMQ didn't even start whenever I try accessing the console with the user/password specified for read only user I get `!role error`.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer in [here](https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/202653688-How-can-fine-grained-access-control-be-enabled-for-the-ActiveMQ-administrative-console-2008351-draft-) I had to change class="org.eclipse.jetty.http.security.Constraint" to class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Constraint" in step number 1

Answer (score 0):

Links to Pivotal are dead. For those who want a simple solution you can change these lines from `jetty.xml` :

```
<bean id="securityConstraintMapping" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintMapping">
    <property name="constraint" ref="securityConstraint" />
    <property name="pathSpec" value="/api/*,/admin/*,*.jsp" />
</bean>
<bean id="adminSecurityConstraintMapping" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintMapping">
    <property name="constraint" ref="adminSecurityConstraint" />
    <property name="pathSpec" value="*.action" />
</bean>
```

to

```
<bean id="securityConstraintMapping" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintMapping">
    <property name="constraint" ref="securityConstraint" />
    <property name="pathSpec" value="/api/*,*.jsp,*.html,*.png,*.css,/admin/js/*" />
</bean>
<bean id="adminSecurityConstraintMapping" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintMapping">
    <property name="constraint" ref="adminSecurityConstraint" />
    <property name="pathSpec" value="*.action" />
</bean>
```